# C++ 2d array from fstream not being stored correctly

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Create Text File to store the Values
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE] = { 5, 10, 8, 7, 3, 4, 9, 6, 2, 1 };
int store_count;
ofstream outputFile;
outputFile.open("TenNumbers.txt");
for (store_count = 0; store_count < ARRAY_SIZE; store_count++) {
    outputFile << numbers[store_count] << endl;
}
outputFile.close();

int count = 0;
int num_row1[5];
int num_row2[5];
int nums_array[2][5];
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("TenNumbers.txt");
while (count < 5 && inputFile >> num_row1[count])
    cout << num_row1[count] << endl;
    // Store value into 2d Array
    count++;
    while (count < 10 && inputFile >> num_row2[count])
        cout << num_row2[count] << endl;
        // Store value into 2d Array
        count++;
inputFile.close();
cout << endl;
return 0;
};
```

This is the Output for the File it is reading and the Array that is producing the error:

This is the file numbers that need to be in the 2d array
5
10
8
7
3
4
9
6
2
1

This is what the 2d array shows
1
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460
-858993460

Comment: You're missing some `{ }` on that inner while statement. Nor do I think you should be using the same variable for both loops.

Comment: Not sure I like that edit @Chris. Normally I'm all for proper indentation in questions, but in this case I think that part of the bug was the bad indentation.

Comment: That's a fair point. I decided to roll it back so that the OP's likely source of error is preserved, rather than retaining the edit to make it more clear what's going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Your error almost certainly resides in this type of code.

```
while (count < 5 && inputFile >> num_row1[count])
    cout << num_row1[count] << endl;
    // Store value into 2d Array
    count++;
```

If we indent this more correctly, we get:

```
while (count < 5 && inputFile >> num_row1[count])
    cout << num_row1[count] << endl;
    // Store value into 2d Array

count++;
```

The `count++;` statement is not within the while loop, so `count` never changes. This means you're never filling more than one element in your array, and the rest are uninitialized, which means their contents are undefined.

You probably meant to write:

```
while (count < 5 && inputFile >> num_row1[count]) {
    cout << num_row1[count] << endl;
    // Store value into 2d Array
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you don't need `;` after `#include <...>` because `#include <...>` is not a statement. The `;` after it is just evaluated into a null statement.

Also

```cpp
while (count < 5 && inputFile >> num_row1[count])
    cout << num_row1[count] << endl;
    // Store value into 2d Array
    count++;
    while (count < 10 && inputFile >> num_row2[count])
        cout << num_row2[count] << endl;
        // Store value into 2d Array
        count++;
```

I think that you meant this:

```cpp
while (count1 < 5 && inputFile >> num_row1[count1])
{
    std::cout << num_row1[count1] << std::endl; // change to different variable names
    // Store value into 2d Array
    count++;
    while (count2 < 10 && inputFile >> num_row2[count])
    {
        std::cout << num_row2[count2] << std::endl;
        // Store value into 2d Array
        count++;
    } // block scope with proper indentation

}
```